# Services and protocols to restrict torrent traffic at a university campus

Tags: blocking, network-protocols, bittorrent

Which service has the ability of blocking bit-torrent traffic on a subnet network, snmp or bgp? Are these protocols useful for such blocking ?

Comment: The correct service is the service provided by admninistration and rule building. (Read: Forbid them to use it, log it and if they keep abusing it ban them from the network.)

Answer (score 1):

[SNMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snmp) is a network management protocol and [BGP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bgp) is a routing protocol. To restrict any type of traffic, you usually use a firewall not another type of protocol!